# Unable to resolve table <Имя таблицы>

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Писал дискорд бота, и в один прекрасный момент PyCharm стал говорить: "Unable to resolve table 'players'". Таблица подключена, диалект правильный, директорию 10 раз проверил, все норм(должно быть..)

```py
import random as ran
import sqlite3 as sql
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from emojis import *
from settings import settings

conn = sql.connect('G:\IceRPG\players.sqlite')
with conn:
    cur: sql.Cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()
```

[image: Выделено розовым - то что выдает ошибку]

Как и чем это исправить?

Comment: Код должен быть в виде текста, а не картинки. Могу предположить, что вы случайно написали `players` с русской буквой либо в коде, либо в самой БД. Внешне это незаметно, я бы проверил это в первую очередь.

Comment: Несколько смущает что тут не экранированная строка с путем `sql.connect('G:\IceRPG\players.sqlite')`, `'G:\IceRPG\players.sqlite'`, у `I` и `p` похоже нет слеш-последовательностей (в отличии от, например, n или t), но я бы всегда это учитывал т.е.: `r'G:\IceRPG\players.sqlite'`. Причем, если бы по тому пути не было бы базы, то ее драйвер создал, а узнать об этом можно или проверкой файла по пути (через os.path или pathlib) или ошибкой, т.к. у пустой базы и таблиц не будет